# Whats the best type of connector for test equipment?

Tags: connector, isolation, test-equipment

I am selecting the components to use for a tester I am developing.

I am looking at various types of board to board connectors.

The requirements are:

- Rated to least 2A.
- Rated to ~200v.
- *High Isolation, in the order of 1Gohm (most important)
- Pitch no less then 1mm.
- 2 rows preferred.
- Available in large sizes, 50-200 range.

In the past I have used card edge but it has always been hard to get in and out and the connectors don't always make good contact.

[image]

Another connector I am looking at is the rectangular board to board connectors.
They look promising but I don't know what the isolation resistance for these are though.

[image]

Also there is DB connectors which have high current ratings and isolation resistance for the expensive ones. How do these compare to the ones above?

[image]

Most connector datasheets I see just talk about the dimensions and footprint. It is hard to tell what type of connector is best suited for high isolation while also being able to meet all the other requirements.

Has anyone also had a design that required accurate sourcing and sensing of multiple channels or know of anything purpose built for this kind of thing?

Comment: This is a shopping question and thus off topic here. It may, however, be possible to rephrase it as something more on-topic. I honestly find myself in the position of wanted to both VTC as off-topic _and_ upvote, as it's a well-presented question, certainly much better than many others here... I'll withhold the upvote unless and until it becomes more on-topic though.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase it

Comment: why don't you simply match the connector on the tester to the connector on the device being tested?

Comment: This is all of a shopping question, strongly based in opinion and preference, and most critically *unanswerable* without considering more of your need.  For example, "testing" means very different things when done *in the course of development*, when long amounts of staff time are spent interacting with an individual high-value item, vs when a lot of product needs to quickly move down the line.  In the earlier circumstances you want a connection that is reliable in use and manipulation, while in a fast moving production line you probably want spring pins or something fast to connect.

Comment: If I asked what type of OPAMP is best for feedback loops nobody would say it was a shopping question. This is the same question but with connectors. Spring load pins, I forgot about that one. that maybe the answer.

Comment: At high voltage gradients, insulators become very electrically nonlinear. Because of this, isolation is much more commonly rated as a maximum voltage, rather than as a resistance.

Comment: Ah ok, so a high voltage rating would correspond to a high isolation resistance.

Comment: Most any DB style connector or even 100 mil dual row headers can tolerate 200 volts. I have used them at 1500 VDC for leakage test in ribbon cables. Therein lies the problem. **The weak spots are the cable and the board layout at the connector.**

Comment: You could skip pins in a connector to increase isolation/creepage distance

Comment: Found one! It has a really high voltage and current rating. http://suddendocs.samtec.com/catalog_english/ipt1.pdf

Comment: Regarding pogo connectors, are the jigs that press the boards onto the pins sold as as hardware or typically custom made? I can't really find anything on the internet or know what key words to use.